# Чи можна сказати "Корінь функції ƒ — це елемент х в якому функція обертається у нуль"?

Tags: вибір-слова

Чи можна сказати "В математиці, корінь (або нуль) функції ƒ — це елемент х із області визначення в якому функція обертається у нуль" (а не "приймає нульове значення")?

Answer (score 3):

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах наводить 12 тлумачень дієслова `обертатися`, серед яких є і [наступне](http://sum.in.ua/s/obertatysja):

> 6. Переходити з одного стану в інший; перетворюватися. *Під ногами пересохла земля **оберталась на** порох (Петро Панч, В дорозі, 1959, 46);*  <…>
>      //  Докорінно змінювати свої функції, стан, призначення і т. ін. *Сільрада **обернулася на** оперативний штаб розгорнутого наступу на віковічні традиції селянської обмеженості (Григорій Епік, Тв., 1958, 208); Вже офіцер став електриком, сержант **обернувся** теслярем, а снайпер — художником-декоратором (Олесь Гончар, I, 1954, 445);  * Образно. На приморському безлюдді **Обернувся я в** дитину (Агатангел Кримський, Вибр., 1965, 40);*

Це визначення хоч і наводить приклади з художніх, а не технічних текстів, але підтверджує можливість вживання прийменників у(в)/на або орудного відмінку.

У Вікіпедії зазвичай вживається варіант з прийменником `в` (див. напр. [тут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F#.D0.92.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.96_2), [тут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97) і [тут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.88.D0.B0_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.91.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D1.86.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BE_.E2.80.94_.D0.9A.D0.BE.D1.88.D1.96)).

Comment: Іще в старих підручниках: «[Крім того, вважаємо, що функція обертається в нуль в точках, розміщених на великій відстані від джерела струму А, і ми досить точно знаємо цю відстань.](//books.google.com/books?id=HFcWAQAAIAAJ&q=%22функція+обертається%22)» (1968), «[Апроксимація здійснювалася у межах х = 0,20 сек, оскільки далі автокореляційна функція оберталася у нуль.](//books.google.com/books?id=wUTVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22функція+оберталася%22)» (1970).

Comment: Теоретично можна навіть без *-ся*: якесь значення аргумента може [обертати функцію](//www.google.com/search?q=%22обертає+функцію%22) в/на щось.

Comment: Цей коментар теж тоже може бути відповіддю.

Comment: За наведеним посиланням на СУМ є навіть приклад ближчий за значенням: "Обертатися (обернутися) внівець (нанівець) див. нанівець; Обертатися (обернутися) в ніщо — зникати без сліду. Із нічого.. ніщо виникати не може; Що ж народилось, не може так само в ніщо обернутись (Микола Зеров, Вибр., 1966, 140)"

Answer (score 2):

У словосполученні "...функція дорівнює нулю (п'яти, шести...)"...  не відчуваю ніякої прісності. Воно зовсім не ріже мені слух. Навпаки його вживають постійно у математичному середовищі. 
Взагалі-то, можу навести п'ять синонімічних, математично правильних побудов: „набуває значення“, приймає значення“, „дорівнює значенню“, „стає рівною“, „перетворюється у“. 
„Обертається“ у старих книжках дійсно вживалося. Зараз менше. Думаю, що причина у словосполученні „обертається функція чи матриця“, яке також означає знаходження оберненої функції чи матриці. Крім того, є ще термін „обернене число“. Обидва терміни мають зовсім інше тлумачення, ніж обернутися у якесь значення. Либонь, це сприяло виходу з ужитку цього вислову. Тим паче, що наявні 5 його замінників (а може й більше).

Answer (score -3):

Ну може хіба що "...функція дорівнює нулю (п'яти, шести...)"... Але це вже занадто прісно..

Comment: Це відповідь? Чи це Ви випадково не туди написали?

Comment: -1: Якщо це мала бути власна відповідь на запитання, то вона має відповідати критеріям відповіді.

Comment: Це краще, аніж нічого.

Comment: Суто математично, відповідь Kosarar'а повністю бездоганна. Тому ставити за це -1 бал безґлуздо. Якщо не можна збагнути математичної суті, то не ставте -1 через це.

Comment: Це, ІМХО, не є відповіддю на власне запитання. Бо «в цій точці значення функції дорівнює нулю» сказати очевидно можна — але це ніяк на відповідає на те, чи можна сказати «функція в точці обертається в нуль».

Comment: До речі, по-моєму, варто казати «**значення** функції дорівнює нулю», а не «функція дорівнює нулю», бо останнє трішки математично двозначне.